# load csv file into mysql using batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file, mysql, csv, sql

I am looking for help to load a .csv file into MySQL Server using batch and I have few basic questions.

**Issues:**

1)  The CSV file data may have , (comma) in between (Ex: description), so how can I make import handling these data?

2)  To load CSV from Excel then the data that have comma are enclosed within "" (double quotes) [as the below example] so how do the import can handle this?

**Here is the sample CSV with header:**

```
name,id,Subject,ExamDate,Mark,Description
Prabhat,1,Math,2/10/2013,25,Test data for prabhat.
Murari,2,Science,2/11/2013,24,"Test data for his's test, where we can test 2nd ROW, Test."
sanjay,3,Science,,25,Test Only.
```

**The SQL statement used to import:**

```
load data local infile "c:\\eqa\\project\\input.csv" into table request character set latin1 fields terminated by',' lines terminated by'\n' ignore 1 lines
```

How can I do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `load data local infile` and [Loading Data into a Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html) using MySQL, there is a simple solution which is provided as part of this functionality which will help you to resolve this issue.

You simply want to be sure to include the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` subclause as part of the `FIELD` clause in the MySQL syntax you are using—
below is an example of this.

```
load data local infile "c:\\eqa\\project\\input.csv" 
into table request 
character set latin1 
fields terminated by','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
lines terminated by'\n' 
ignore 1 lines
```

This tells MySQL the input file has field values that are both ***enclosed by double quotes*** and ***separated by commas***—All characters between double quotes will then be imported.

---

### Further Resources

- [Loading Data into a Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loading-tables.html)
- [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

  - > `LOAD DATA INFILE` can be used to read files obtained from external sources. For example, many programs can export data in comma-separated values (CSV) format, such that lines have fields separated by commas and enclosed within double quotation marks, with an initial line of column names. If the lines in such a file are terminated by carriage return/newline pairs, the statement shown here illustrates the field- and line-handling options you would use to load the file:
    >
    > ```
    > LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_name
    >   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    >   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    >   IGNORE 1 LINES;
    > ```
    >
    > ---
    >
    > For input, the `ENCLOSED BY` character, if present, is stripped from
    >   the ends of field values. (This is true regardless of whether
    >   `OPTIONALLY` is specified; `OPTIONALLY` has no effect on input
    >   interpretation.) Occurrences of the `ENCLOSED BY` character preceded
    >   by the `ESCAPED BY` character are interpreted as part of the current
    >   field value.
    >
    > If the field begins with the `ENCLOSED BY` character, instances of
    >   that character are recognized as terminating a field value only if
    >   followed by the field or line `TERMINATED BY` sequence. To avoid
    >   ambiguity, occurrences of the `ENCLOSED BY` character within a field
    >   value can be doubled and are interpreted as a single instance of the
    >   character. For example, if `ENCLOSED BY '"'` is specified, quotation
    >   marks are handled as shown here:
    >
    > ```
    > "The ""BIG"" boss"  -> The "BIG" boss
    > The "BIG" boss      -> The "BIG" boss
    > The ""BIG"" boss    -> The ""BIG"" boss
    > ```
    >
    > [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)