# Scheduling Batch File to Run Python Code to upload data to mysql

Tags: batch, python, mysql

I created a batch file to upload CVSs to a MySQL database using python pandas_tosql. When I manually run the batch file it works fine. When I try to run it from scheduler it appears to work correctly(I input a winsound.beep tone and it makes a sound) however, the data doesn't appear in my database. I'm thinking there is a setting in MySQL to reject it, but cannot figure it out. The database is homebrewed for analytics only so I have free range to change anything I want. It's mainly just to store data for exploratory reasoning.

```
c:
call C:\Users\hknighton\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
pythonw C:\Users\hknighton\dump\sql.py
conda deactivate
```

The python script

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import winsound
frequency = 2500  # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
duration = 1500  # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
directory = os.getcwd()






from IPython.display import clear_output
def update_progress(progress):
    bar_length = 20
    if isinstance(progress, int):
        progress = float(progress)
    if not isinstance(progress, float):
        progress = 0
    if progress < 0:
        progress = 0
    if progress >= 1:
        progress = 1
    block = int(round(bar_length * progress))
    clear_output(wait = True)
    text = "Progress: [{0}] {1:.1f}%".format( "#" * block + "-" * (bar_length - block), progress * 100)
    print(text)




engine = create_engine('mysql://root:password!@localhost:3306/ceesmart')










num_files = 0
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        num_files +=1
num_files





i = 1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            data = pd.read_csv(file)
            file2 = str(file)
            data = data[pd.notnull(data['Time'])]
            data = data.drop_duplicates()
        data.to_sql("hourlydata", con=engine, index=True, index_label='id', if_exists='append')
        print(i)
        i = i + 1
        update_progress(i/num_files)

winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

Comment: Curiously the sound doesn't occur when I run the batch file directly.

Comment: *WHO* is the batch file being run as?  When you click on it, it's you.  When you run it from the scheduler, I bet it isn't.

Comment: Are you referring to the Run the task from the following account? It lists my account.

Comment: Just to make sure, I would temporarily add a line to the batch file to pipe the current domain/user to a text file when it runs.  It still sounds like permissions to me.  What exactly does the batch file look like?  Is it possible that pyton needs something that isn't in the environment when the scheduler runs it?  Are you using [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1392132/load-csv-file-into-mysql-using-batch?rq=1) method?

Comment: Posting the batch file (sanitized of sensitive info) could help us help you.

Comment: Posted the batch and underlying python code

Answer (score 2):

This *should* be a comment. But I haven't yet got the "cred" to create one.

May I suggest that you look in your MySQL (error) log shortly *after* the timer fires for your task/cron/... That will hold any information as to what happened, eg; login failed for someuser@someplace PASSWORD SOMEPASSWORD.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I run into this it's because the scheduler doesn't open the files in the same directory as the script does when you run it manually.

I suspect that os.listdir(directory) is defaulting to C:\Users\hknighton\ and not finding any csv files?

Comment: You were right! I added os.chdir("C:/Users/hknighton/dump") to the python script and it worked. Thanks